# Model test in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I've some problems with my model tests in ruby.  When I try to use a test of validation, the test produces an error. I created a new model (child model) which has the following validations

```
 class Child < ApplicationRecord

   has_many :relations, :dependent => :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :relations
   belongs_to :user
   validates :user, presence: true
   validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
   validates :city, presence: true, :on => :create
     validates :postalcode, presence: true, numericality: true
       validates :streed, presence: true
         validates :add_number, presence: true

 validates :disability, presence:true, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
 validates :halal, presence:true, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
 validates :koscha, presence:true, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
 validates :vegetarian, presence:true, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
 validates :vegan, presence:true, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
 validates :allday, presence:true, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }

 validates :gender, presence: true
```

I would like to test my model and wanna use as first test the validation of the child:

```
   def setup
     @child = Child.new(name: "Example Child", city: "Example City", postalcode: 13, streed: "Example Street",
                  add_number: 3, disability: true, gender: 1, halal: true, koscha: false,
                   vegetarian: false, vegan: false, allday:true, user: "hallo")
   end

    test "should be valid" do
      assert @child.valid?
    end
```

and my fixtures for the children look like this:

```
 one:
   name: MyString
   city: MyString
   postalcode: 1
   streed: MyString
   add_number: 1
   disability: false
   halal: false
   koscha: false
   vegetarian: false
   vegan: false
   allday: false
   gender: 1
   user_id: 3
```

I have the problem, that my validation test produces the following error `false to be truth` and I can't see, what I've done wrong...
I think, it's a very simple fault...
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can output errors. assert @child.valid? , @child.errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my validation test produces the following error false to be truth and I can't see, what I've done wrong

This means that `@child.valid?` returns false. Not what `assert` expects.

I too don't see what you did wrong. Most likely, some validation failing. It's trivial to find out which one. Just inspect `@child.errors`. Like this, for example.

```
test "should be valid" do
  is_valid = @child.valid? # trigger validation
  p @child.errors unless is_valid

  assert is_valid
end
```

---

I'm betting on this one:

```
user: "hallo"
```

This doesn't look like a valid user object.

Comment: yes you're right, this doesn't work. Thank you very much! Should I use my fixture example as user?

Comment: unfortunately not, there is a problem with this `user`...I'm not sure how to solve this